# SketchFlow WP7 Navigation Buggy

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, sketchflow

I'm making a Sketchflow WP7 application which is working fine, except Navigation is sometimes buggy. Sometimes when I go to a screen and try and click it doesn't work, some times it does. I'm using the MouseLeftButtonDown Event to trigger it. After it 'freezes' I can no longer navigate via the map either, though before it freezes I can. I'm not sure if any errors are thrown because I'm not aware of a real time silverlight console. Sketchflow doesn't have a 'Debug Project' option only a 'Run Project' one.

It's very unpredictable, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't (though some links are more unreliable than others). Sometimes it gets stuck in different screens. I've tested this across browsers and computers and while sometimes a new browser occasionally has a better success rate, something always gets stuck.

I'm afraid I'm probably leaving out some details so feel free to ask for them.  I'm not really very familiar with Silverlight and Sketchflow, I'm just working on a prototype so it seems like I shouldn't have to deal with any code based issues...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you fixed your problem? I am dealing with the same issue and I am stuck.

Comment: No, unfortunately I never found a bug fix. It was highly irreproducable. Sometimes it would happen, sometimes it wouldn't. In the end I hadn't done much work so I threw out the entire application, made it again and it worked... No idea what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look for a Click Event rather than MouseButtonDown as that could be anything, it doesnt mean MouseButton Down, MouseButton Up, which resembles a click. this is just the same as if you use your finger to touch the screen, this would also trigger the MouseButton Down Eventhandler

so if I was you try and use the Click eventhandler for your navigation.

Comment: Even better use the Tap event (WP7.1 SDK only, or in the Toolkit if you're on 7.0). That way you won't get phantom "clicks" as you scroll through pivots or lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the same project in VS (including the free express editions) and run it in the debugger from there to see if an exception is being thrown. That might help narrow down the problem.